# Tinting the background of an outlined Material Components button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I'm trying to create an [outlined Material Components button](https://www.material.io/design/components/buttons.html#outlined-button), however I need it to have a semi-transparent background in addition to the stroke.

This is my XML code so far:

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:backgroundTint="#CFFF"
    app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

And this is what this looks like:

[image: Button with 2dp stroke]

The issue is that some of the background is visible outside the stroke around the button (the larger the stroke width, the more white pixels getting out).

For example, here's a `5dp` stroke:

[image: Button with 5dp stroke]

Is there a way to fix this, a better way to set the background color, or anything?

Comment: Just faced the same problem, I had to change the corner radius to get rid of this effect

Answer (score 4):

Just use the **`Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton`** style:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:backgroundTint="#3ad64f"
        .../>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you create a style of that you have to remove the  `app:` In my example this style is called `SecondButton`

```
 <style name="SecondButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/SecondButtonTheme</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/second_button_back</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/second_button_text</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/second_button_text</item>
</style>
```

Use it like that in you

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/SecondButton"
    .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your button in drawables directly in xlm based on this :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="backgroundcolor"/>
        <stroke android:color="strokecolor" android:width="2dp" />
        <!--corners allow us to make the rounded corners button-->
        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

founded here : https://android--code.blogspot.fr/2015/01/android-rounded-corners-button.html

and use it like this in your layout  :

```
 android:background="@drawable/nameofbutton.xml"
```

Comment: While this is a solution for a regular Button, I'd like to use the new Material Button for its extra capabilities, and this doesn't seem to play nice with that.